# IP Address not getting updated to IIS once connected with new network

Tags: visual-studio, iis, localhost

I am using `Conveyor by Keyoti` visual studio 2019 extension I ran application on my home network and accessed that application over my other remote device successfully.

[image]

But when I get connected to my university network the `Conveyor by Keyoti` failed to update the `IP ADDRESS` over my university network and kept showing the home's network IP ADDRESS due to which localhost failed to connect.

I deleted and re-installed the extension many times but its not updating the IP ADDRESS due to which I am unable to access the localhost.What could be the possible reason for this and how to update it as my network changes ?

Comment: It's an old post, but today I faced the same thing in VS2022 with Conveyor+. Seems Conveyor+ is not updating the list with IP addresses until VS is closed and re-openend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the IP address here?And have you tried to reset all settings?
[image]

It looks like this extension is reading IPv4 ip address from all of my network adapter. So did you see 192.168.x.x in your cmd "ipconfig" command line?